# Feature selection using eigenvalues and eigenvectors in Python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, correlation

I have 5 lists that represent numerical vectors. I want to identify the vector that has the highest correlation with the first vector.

I also have their eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Using them, how can I identify which vectors are highly correlated with `a1`?

My data:

```
a1 = [1, 23, 4, 51, 62, 7, 8, 43, 1, 29]
a2 = [5, 45, 32, 51, 60, 7, 8, 35, 10, 31]
a3 = [13, 3, 64, 35, 36, 37, 48, 3, 31, 1]
a4 = [5, 53, 34, 51, 61, 73, 81, 413, 1, 33]
a5 = [3, 3, 1, 5, 6, 3, 8, 3, 1, 3]

list1 = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]
```

This is the code I used to find the correlations:

```
for i in range(5):
    cov_mat = np.cov([a1, list1[i]])
    val, vec = np.linalg.eig(cov_mat)
    print(val)
    print(vec)

    print("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to find the vector with the highest correlation to `a1`. In your example, you are calculating the covariance between all vectors, whereas you actually want the correlations:

```
np.corrcoef(list1)
# array([[ 1.        ,  0.86675825, -0.23602677,  0.37897762,  0.41113663],
#        [ 0.86675825,  1.        , -0.10780546,  0.16422644,  0.17282495],
#        [-0.23602677, -0.10780546,  1.        , -0.32809557,  0.15695428],
#        [ 0.37897762,  0.16422644, -0.32809557,  1.        ,  0.05856583],
#        [ 0.41113663,  0.17282495,  0.15695428,  0.05856583,  1.        ]])
```

This gives you all pair-wise correlations between all 5 vectors, but you are only interested in the correlations with `a1`:

```
np.corrcoef(list1)[0]
# array([ 1.        ,  0.86675825, -0.23602677,  0.37897762,  0.41113663])
```

Note that the first correlation is 1, and that's because the correlation between `a1` and `a1` is 1, because they are identical.

Also note that the `a2` has the strongest correlation with `a1`

---

On the relation between variables, and how covariance and correlation are similar but different - [towardsdatascience post](https://towardsdatascience.com/let-us-understand-the-correlation-matrix-and-covariance-matrix-d42e6b643c22):

> In simple words, both the terms measure the relationship and the
>   dependency between two variables. “Covariance” indicates the direction
>   of the linear relationship between variables. “Correlation” on the
>   other hand measures both the strength and direction of the linear
>   relationship between two variables

Comment: this is Pearson. I am not looking for it,anyways Thanks

Comment: I don't understand, you are looking for the correlation between two vectors. If you are not looking for Pearson correlation, then what correlation are you looking for?

Comment: there some theories that say we can find Variance of two metric using eigenvalue and eigenvector . and we can use it to analysis the data like which are dependent or which are not.